# Writing MetaData inside HDFS

Tags: hadoop, nutch, indexer

We are using nutch to crawl our intranet site.

We are extracting the meta data in xml file, in the indexing phase(We modified the code of indexer.java), and when ran in local mode it gave us the required metadata.

Now, we thought of using nutch in cluster mode(using hadoop), when we crawled nutch in cluster, we are able to get the index but not the metadata which we used to get previously, in local mode we used(java's IO classes to write meta to files). For hadoop we have changed this to hadoop file system io classes. Yet we are not able to get the meta.

Are there any solution, or are we missing something?

Thanks in advance,
Geo

Answer (score 0):

> We are extracting the meta data in xml file, in the indexing phase(We modified the code of indexer.java), and when ran in local mode it gave us the required metadata.

modifying the indexer is not the best option as illustrated by the issue you've encountered

you could :

- add the metadata as part of the injection (if you want to do that for the seeds only)
- or write a custom indexing plugin : and e.g. get it to load the XML md from a file in conf/

the content of conf/ is added to the job file and is distributed across the nodes of the cluster. There are quite a few examples of indexing plugins in the code.

Maybe you should use the Nutch user list to get a broader audience?